# Парсинг отдельного слова регулярным выражением

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

Пытюсь извлечь логин ROOT из такого исходного текста:

```
<85>login[2775]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/tty1'
```

Использую вот такой код:

```
QRegExp re1_1(".*: (?<username>.*) LOGIN.*");
foreach(const QString& str, strings)
{
    if(re1_1.exactMatch(str))
        qDebug() << "Found: " << ":" << str;
}
```

Скорее всего, проблема в регулярном выражении. Подскажите, где я ошибся, и как она должна выглядеть правильно.

Comment: укажите версию Qt, в Qt4 есть лишь жалкое подобие регулярок, тогда как в 5-й версии уже полноценная реализация.

Comment: Версия QT4 могу перейти на 5-ю

Comment: Если можете, тогда переходите. Зачем использовать устаревшую версию библиотеки?

Comment: Возможно, я неправ, но мне кажется, что это - из пушки по воробьям и куда проще обойтись без регулярных выражений?..

Comment: @Harry если поменяется формат лога, правка регулярки - три минуты с перерывом. Переделка специально написанного парсера может вылиться в долгие часы.

Если же говорить о скорости исполнения, существуют компиляторы из регулярок в готовый парсер.

Answer (score 4):

Вам подойдёт вот такое регулярное выражение:

```
.*:\s+(.*)\s+LOGIN.*
```

Искомый `ROOT` будет в первой группе совпадений(matches).

P.S. То регулярное выражение, что написано у Вас в вопросе, вообще не имеет смысла.

---

Вот как это может выглядеть в коде(должно одинаково работать как в 4-й, так и в 5-й версиях)

```
QString source{"<85>login[2775]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/tty1'"};
QRegExp regexp{R"-(.*:\s+(.*)\s+LOGIN.*)-"};
if(regexp.exactMatch(source))
    qDebug() << "The found login is: " << regexp.cap(1);
```

---

Решение для Qt5 исключительно, с несколько более эффективным регулярным выражением:

```
QString source{"<85>login[2775]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/tty1'"};
QRegularExpression regexp{R"-(.*?:\s+(.*?)\s+LOGIN.*)-"};
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regexp.match(source);
if(match.hasMatch())
    qDebug() << "The found login is: " << match.captured(1);
```

Comment: Не работает. Юзаю так: foreach( const QString& str, strings )
        {
            if(re1.exactMatch( str ))
            {
                qDebug() << "matched LOGIN SUCSESS" << ":" << str;

            }
            qDebug() << "SOURCE: " <<str;
            if(re1_1.exactMatch( str ))
            {
                qDebug() << "OLOLO: " << ":" << str;

            }

        }

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, что значит «не работает»? Какого результата Вы ожидаете?

Comment: @ixSci, а что означает символ "R" в строке с объявлением регулярки?

Comment: @alexis031182, [необработанный литерал](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/12/29/various_literals.aspx#raw_literals)

Comment: @ixSci, ух-ты, полезно, спасибо!

Comment: Исправил баг. Если Вы не согласны- откатите обратно.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ну это не баг, совершенно точно. Решение с не жадным лучше, но вот Qt его не умеет в таком виде.

Comment: @ReinRaus, оказывается в Qt5 новый класс для регулярных выражений появился, добавил код с новым рег. выражением, но исходное я исправлять не стану, т.к. для Qt4 только оно и подойдёт. Поэтому, оставлю его как универсальное решение.

Comment: Тогда это баг. `<85>login[2775]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/LOGIN'` на таком тексте найдет не то, что нужно

Comment: @ReinRaus, давайте исходить из реальных текстов, а не из всевозможных. В реальном мире появление `/dev/LOGIN` *весьма* маловероятно.

Comment: @ReinRaus, к тому же Вы не правы, на приведённом Вами тексте, моё исходное регулярное выражение «поймает» то, что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем использовать обертки Qt, если стандартный С++ предоставляет работу с регуляркой?

```
std::string s ("<85>login[2775]: ROOT LOGIN  on '/dev/tty1'");
std::regex e (".*:\\s+(.*?)\\s+LOGIN.*");
std::smatch m;
if(std::regex_search (s,m,e)) std::cout << m[1];
```

Comment: Стандартные регулярки не умеют `QString`